# C#, Не удается запустить службу Windows

Tags: c#, windows-7

Написал службу Windows на C#. При запуске выдается ошибка: Не удалось запустить службу TFFU на Локальный компьютер. Ошибка 1053: Служба не ответила на запрос своевременно. ОС Windows 7 SP1 x86. При этом эта же служба работает запускается на Windows 7 SP1 x64 и Windows 10. Службу устанавливаю с помощью InstallUtil. Служба пустая. Что может быть не так?

```
public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CanStop = true;
        this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
        this.AutoLog = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //trans.StartTransfer();
        timer.Start();
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
        timer.Interval = 30000; //number in milisecinds  
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
     //Тут должна быть программа
    }
```

Comment: При таком типе ошибок самое первое на что нужно смотреть - на то, чтобы при старте сервиса не выполнялось никаких долгих операций. Версия ОС вообще не причём.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле всё было просто. На компьютере была установлена версия .Net 4.0, а в Visual Studio проект по умолчанию был создан под версию 4.6.1. После обновления версии, служба запустилась без всяких проблем.